# Showing multiple raster images on map QGIS 3.20

Tags: raster, qgis-3, kml

I am using multiple raster images that are all geo-referenced, have different icons and  are part of a large mosaic. Although I have linked all of them on the attribute table and view each image, I still can not show them all in the map. I also try to use the raster image fill but the QGIS 3.20 is giving me back multiple copies of specific piece, not the whole pack of them.

Is there a way to show every specific icon on the map thus to connect all the pieces of the puzzle?

This group of raster images is a large KML file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved!!!

For anyone to whom it may concern.

Firstly we need to save the file as a shape file. Also it is needed to save all the raster images into a folder.

Secondly we should add in the attribute table the path of the image files as a new column eg. Path and using the function concat to  update each row. as:
concat('C:/Users/acer/Desktop/...../',"icon") where icon is the name of column that includes the names of the raster images and update them all.

And at the end.

To show them all we should go to symbology --> Raster image fill --> select the field type the new column that we have previously created eg. Path  and the Qgis automatically generate all the raster images into the specific polygons that are matched.

Comment: Nice!  If I understand your answer correctly you did not need to use the widget that is displayed in your original question. Is that correct?

Comment: I use the widget attachment  to confirm the raster icons  with the images that are displayed on the program. Just only for help nothing more!