# QGIS 3.34 - How to show correct image width/zoom in KML multiple raster background image

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, kml, import

I'm trying to import in QGIS a KML file with multiple background tile images (all georeferenced) into a grid. The images are located in a separate folder and inside the layer data there's a field with the URL of every single image.

I'm able to load each image into the grid as Raster Symbol (using a dynamic value for the URL) but all images are shown wrong for width/zoom.

I tried to use a fixed width (using tile width in pixel) but problem remains.

I'm now trying with a dynamic parameter but I can't find any valid solution.

P.S. something similar is reported in this old post:

[Showing multiple raster images on map QGIS 3.20](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403768/showing-multiple-raster-images-on-map-qgis-3-20/478606?newreg=0dad89db5f2d4942bc6911b6414d72bb)

[image: Here the Symbol Raster section configuration]

Comment: as far as I know, the KML format won't include tiles/rasters/tiffs/images. KMLs only include vectors. KMZs do have capacity for images, but you would need a plugin for QGIS to be importing them. Tell us more about what you are doing please.

Comment: @BJW OP has a vector KML file of polygon geometry, and the polygon symbol is set to Raster Image Fill, with the image source from a field in the KML file. The problem is how to get the raster fill symbol to scale properly. OP, it's hard for us to assist without any further info on how the images were originally scaled/refereneced. Can you try changing the image width (Larghezza immagine) using percentage instead of pixels and play around with the values? And maybe change Coord mode (Modalità coord) to from Object (Oggetto) to Viewport